# UIViewPropertyAnimator cancels other animation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have an animation made with `UIViewPropertyAnimator`. This animation shows or hide a view.

I have a switch button, and when I click on it, it will toggle the `isShowingView` and therefore show or hide the view.

But if for exemple, I hide the view while the "show" animation is still in progress, it cancels instantly the show animation, and the view just disappears without any animation.

Note that this doesn't happen with a simple `UIView.animate` instead of `UIViewPropertyAnimator` .

Here's some dummy code that replicates the issue :

```
    var isShowingView = false

    func onButtonClick() {
        isShowingView.toggle()
        refreshView()
    }

    func refreshView() {
        let timing = UICubicTimingParameters(controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.4, y: 0.0),
                                             controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 1.0))

        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, timingParameters: timing)

       animator.addAnimations {
            self.myView.alpha = isShowingView ? 1 : 0
        }

        animator.addCompletion { position in
            guard position == .end else { return }

            if self.myView.alpha == 0.0 && isShowingView {
                print("Bug here, at this moment the animation is broken <-----")
            }
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
```

Is this the expected behavior? What could I do to prevent this?

Comment: Where are you *"hiding the view"*? What is `isShowingView`? Is your goal to "fade-out" the view and then set `.isHidden = true`?

Comment: I've edited my question, is it better now ?

Comment: You are throwing away the animator and replacing it with another. Hence the animations are not additive.

Comment: A property animator is eminently interruptible / changeable. It's just that you're using it totally incorrectly. Look at cancel2 case3 for the general idea. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/1adc246acc4fd770b7d5c7c0fb0f2cb8985f7675/bk2ch04p133cancelAnimation/ch17p484cancelAnimation/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks a lot matt ! You can post an answer if you want, I'll validate it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @matt said, the issue is that recreating a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` interrupts the current one.

The solution is to retain the property animator :

```
    var isShowingView = false

    let timing = UICubicTimingParameters(controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0.4, y: 0.0),
                                         controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 1.0))

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, timingParameters: timing)

    func onButtonClick() {
        isShowingView.toggle()
        refreshView()
    }

    func refreshView() {
        animator.addAnimations {
            self.myView.alpha = isShowingView ? 1 : 0
        }

        animator.addCompletion { position in
            guard position == .end else { return }

            if self.myView.alpha == 0.0 && isShowingView {
                print("Bug here, at this moment the animation is broken <-----")
            }
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
```